# Is the following matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1235 &2344 &1234 &1990\\
2124 & 4123& 1990& 3026 \\
1230 &1234 &9095 &1230\\
1262 &2312& 2324 &3907 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly, its determinant is not zero and, hence, the matrix is invertible.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Is there a pattern among these entries?

Comment: I don't know which one is easier, but you could try to row-reduce it. This way, it's invertible if and only if it is full-rank.

Comment: There is no obvious pattern from the eigenvalue/eigenvectors or the svd.

Comment: "Clearly"?? $\ $

Comment: Yeah...that "clearly" is the way some have to say "Hey, I already calculated (or better: some programm did it for me) this ugly thing's determinant and found out it is not zero...so I'll show off and tell you that "cloearly" it is not zero!"

Comment: It's clearly 1664606914601.

Answer (score 515, accepted):

Find the determinant.  To make calculations easier, work modulo $2$! The diagonal is $1$'s, the rest are $0$'s.  The determinant is odd, and therefore non-zero.

Comment: Since I'm not cool enough to ask in Andre' Nicolas' comments about his solution, I am asking Andre Nicolas' or anybody else in this answer body: why can we go from a what I assume is $M_4 \left( \mathbb{Z} \right)$ to $M_4 \left( \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \right)$? I like the idea for its simplicity but will this always work if we start with a matrix in $M_4 \left( \mathbb{Z} \right)$ or in general $M_n \left( \mathbb{Z} \right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Modulo "moves into" addition, multiplication, and the base of exponentiation, ie $a + bc^d \mod n = (a \mod n) + (b \mod n)(c\mod n)^d \mod n$. Since the determinant is a polynomial in the matrix entries, reducing the entries modulo $n$ does not change the value of the determinant module $n$.

Comment: @user7530 How is the determinant a polynomial in the matrix entries? Why does this (non-zero) result, for the determinant modulo $n$ agree with the result of original determinant?

Comment: @MusséRedi You can see this straight from the permutation definition of the determinant: the determinant is a linear combination of products of the matrix entries. Or you can see by induction from Laplace's formula that the determinant is polynomial.

Comment: @user7530 Okay, I was thinking about the usual expression of a polynomial of some variable but by polynomial you mean a linear combination of products of the matrix entries. Could you also answer my second question?

Comment: @MusséRedi For your second question, it doesn't. But $(\det M)\mod 2 = \det(M\mod 2) \mod 2$ so if the determinant is 1 mod 2, it must be odd and therefore nonzero mod nothing.

Comment: @André Nicolas  If the det(m mod 2) would have been even then what does it imply? what I got that, if its odd then only it implies that the original determinant is non zero.  If its even it does not convey anything. Means in case of even result the original determinant may be zero or non zero. Am I right?

Comment: You are  right, if the determinant modulo $2$ were $0$, we could draw no conclusion about whether the matrix is invertible. (But another modulus might yield useful information.)