# Proving if $x$ is an even integer then $x^2 -6x +5$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $x$ is an even integer, then $x^2 - 6x + 5$ is odd.

My solution (direct proving):
$$ x = 2k$$
$$ x^2 - 6x + 5 = 4k^2 -12k + 5 $$
$$ 4k^2 -12k + 4 + 1 = 2(2k^2-6k+2)+1$$ which is by definition is odd.
Is my solution correct?

Comment: yes. Also, $x^2-6x+5=(x-1)(x-5)$ both factors are odd

Comment: how can you tell? can you use it in a direct proof?

Comment: even - odd =odd and odd*odd=odd

Comment: But the fact that @vincentbelkin is showing such a statement probably means he shouldn't cite that unless he proves it as well. His way is more direct unless he can take odd*odd = odd as given.

Answer (score 2):

It's excellent. Any integer of the form $2m+1$ is odd. You just need to say that your original $k$ is an integer and so, too, is $2k^2-6k+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Very nicely done: When you use the premise that $x$ is an even integer, so that $x = 2k$, you need only add:

..."for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. And so $4k^2 -12k + 4 + 1 = 2(2k^2-6k+2)+1$ is an odd integer."

Note also (alternatively), that, if $x$ is even, then there exists a $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x = 2k$. $$x = 2k \implies x^2-6x+5=(x-1)(x-5) \implies (2k - 1)(2k-5)\;\;\text{ is necessarily odd}.$$

I do think that *your* route to proving this is the *most direct* - just don't be afraid to use a few *words* here and there, where appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the proof is correct. The same idea shows that if $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial in $\,x\,$ with integer coefficients then, when $\,x\,$ is even, $\,f(x)\,$ has the same parity as its constant coefficient $\, = f(0),\,$ and when $\,x\,$ is odd, $\,f(x)\,$ has the same parity as the sum of the coefficients. This will be clearer *arithmetically* when one learns about modular arithmetic. Then it can be expressed as

$$ f(x) =  f_0 +\cdots + f_n x^n\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\ 2\!:\, \bigg\lbrace\,\begin{eqnarray} x\equiv 0\ &\Rightarrow&\, f(x)\equiv f(0) \equiv f_0\\ x\equiv 1 \ &\Rightarrow&\, f(x)\equiv f(1)\equiv f_0+\cdots + f_n\end{eqnarray}$$

If particular, if the above values are $\,\rm\color{#c00}{both\equiv 1},\,$ then $\,f\,$ takes only odd values, so it does not take the even value $\,0,\,$ therefore $\,f\,$ has no integer roots. Hence we have deduced the following simple

**Theorem** $\  $[(Parity Root Test)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182607/23500) $\ $ A polynomial $\,f(x)$ with integer coefficients 
has no integer roots when its constant coefficient and coefficient sum are $\rm\color{#c00}{both\ odd}$.