# Calculating that determinant is non zero with modulo 2

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

we have the determinant:

$$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
6&1&1\\
4&-2&5\\
2&8&7\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
A stumbled upon this question: [Is the following matrix invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175561/is-the-following-matrix-invertible)

If I apply the modulo 2 procedure to this matrix, I get a zero determinant, which is not true. Why doesn't that procedure work in this case?

Comment: All you know is that the determinant is zero _modulo 2_.

Comment: So the determinant is even. Does that tell you it's $0$?

Comment: well if I compute $$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&1\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$ 
I get a zero determinant, in the answer to the question I linked, it should be non zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo $2$ idea does not work because this determinant, albeit nonzero, is divisible by $2$. (In fact, it is $-306$.) If something is nonzero modulo $2$, it is certainly nonzero, but if something is zero modulo $2$, this only means that it is *even* but doesn't mean it is *zero*.

You can still apply the same technique, but first divide the first column by $2$: you get the determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}3&1&1\\2&-2&5\\1&8&7\end{vmatrix}$$

which is, modulo $2$:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\0&0&1\\1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=1$$

so this new determinant is nonzero, and so the original determinant (which is twice the new determinant) must be nonzero as well.

Comment: Could we also use modulo 1 without using matrix transformations?

Comment: No, every number modulo $1$ is zero because every number is divisible by $1$. Thus, your matrix $\pmod 1$ will always be a zero matrix and you will not be able to conclude anything.

Comment: Oh I see.... But I guess we can use any modulo that is an integer and larger than 1 ?

Comment: @BiliDebili You can use some modulus that happens not to divide the *actual* determinant of the matrix. so in this case $\pmod 4$ would probably work. However, the bigger modulus - the more work to calculate the determinant - until it gets as bad as calculating the original determinant....

Comment: The original determinant is -306, not twice the new determinant, if I am not mistaking.

Comment: @BiliDebili The original determinant is -306, the new determinant is -153, and the original determinant *is* twice the new determinant. (Dividing a row or a column by a number divides the determinant by the same number.)

Answer (score 1):

In the given link, we can conclude that the matrix is invertible since its determinant is **$1$ modulo $2$**, which cannot be $0$, clearly. However, this procedure cannot be used to show that matrix is not invertible, since if it tells you that determinant is **$0$ modulo $2$** the determinant still can be an even number other than $0$.

Comment: So we can use let's say modulo 1 and get a non zero matrix?

Comment: @ArsenBerk Usually modulo $1$ refers to the equivalence relation, for $x,y\in \mathbb R$, that $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @KentaS Yes, you are right. That's just what happens when you struggle with algebra too much. Because in rings, we can say that a unit is a divisor of every element and $1$ is a unit of the ring $\mathbb{R}$. But for this context, I should have said integer instead of real number because of the modulo, as you said. Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: How about this example @ArsenBerk  :

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & \lambda & 1\\
1 & 1 & \lambda\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
If $\lambda$ is even then the diagonal is zero. The determinant is non zero.
But I tried for:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -2\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
And the determinant is zero...why is that so ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but in your first example, if we are considering the determinant in modulo $2$, then determinant also becomes $0$ modulo $2$. And your second example is a determinant whose value is $0$, which is $0$ modulo $2$. So I don't see any problem for your first example to be $0$ modulo $2$.